# Minimal Rectangle Bounding box around a region if an image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi i am working with matlab and trying to select a region using a bounding box. The code is as shown below

```
BW=bwconncomp(I1);
STATS = regionprops(BW, 'FilledArea','BoundingBox','Image');
```

The result is as shown below

[image]

I am trying to obtain an output as shown below. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Learn a bit of PCA! It will help

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I also naturally think of PCA in this context. But while the results should be similar most of the time, it is actually different from the problem of the *smallest enclosing box*. I even found a rather recent paper [comparing those approaches](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.127.5985&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thanks ill surely look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these two codes for the generation of *oriented bounding boxes* on the File Exchange:

- [`orientedBox`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/geom2d/orientedBox.m) in **geom2d** by *David Legland*:

  > `OBOX = orientedBox(PTS)` Computes the oriented bounding box of a set of points.
- [`imOrientedBox`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30402-feret-diameter-and-oriented-box/content//imFeretDiameters/imOrientedBox.m) in **Feret diameter and oriented box** also by *David Legland*

  > `OBB = imOrientedBox(IMG)` Computes the minimum area oriented
  >   bounding box of labels in image `IMG`.

You will probably get what you are looking for from `imOrientedBox`.

Comment: Hello have you used the code before? I am a bit confused with one of its parameters ie. the angles. The default is set to 180. I've tried passing 360 but i get the same result.

Comment: @user2307268: I just had a look at the code. 180 is not really the degree you are passing. It is the number of box-directions between 0° and 180° that will be tested. Which means that the default of 180 means: accuracy should be 1°. If you choose 360 instead, it means: accuracy of the box should be 180°/360 = 0.5°.